# Is there such a thing as a bad unit test?

Tags: unit-testing

Given you can't write tests for dynamic content, outside of this, is there ever a reason you should not add a unit test? Maybe a test project integrity might be considered not necessary, but I could argue this both ways.

***Example:***

Objective-C/xCode = Write a test to make sure fonts are listed in your constants are also listed in your projects info.plist UIAppFonts array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, tests are supposed to adhere to a few key metrics: they should be fast, easy to read and interpret, consistent results, etc.

If any of these (and more) qualities of a good unit test are not met, you will end up with a cost. If the unit tests are slow then you spend time twindling your thumbs or if they are too hard you're spending time interpreting tests instead of writing new ones/code, same goes for tests that have inconsistent results.

Therefore we can say that bad unit tests exist.

However if we look into your concrete example of "should we test X" then that is a lot more subjective.

If something is easy to test like a getter/setter (aka: trivial code) then some might not find it worth their time while others consider it no problem: by adding these quick, small tests you will never encounter an unexpected problem just because someone added logic to their getter/setter and there are no tests to catch any mistakes.

I have no knowledge about Objective-C but at first glance that seems like a reasonable concept to test.

General rule: unless you have an explicit reason *not* to test something, test it.

Answer (score 2):

Unit tests are really just a tool to create a lower watermark for quality of your code.

If you're 100% confident that your code works as intended, then you have enough unit tests. Adding more tests in this case is just a waste of time.

Think "hello world". How many unit tests would you write for that? 1 or 0?

If you're unsure about something, then you need more unit tests. Reasons for this feeling can be:

1. You or someone else just found a bug. Always write unit tests for bugs.
2. Someone asked for a new feature and you're not confident how to implement -> write tests to design the API and to be sure the final result will meet the expectation (and to make sure that everyone knows and agrees on expectations).
3. You are using a new technology and want to document a) how it works and b) how you use it. These tests work as a kind of template when you wonder later "how did I do this?"
4. You just found a bug in a library that you use. When you fix the bug, you should also add a test case that tells you "this bug has now been fixed!" so you don't hunt in the wrong place later.

Examples for bad unit tests:

1. Integration test hiding inside of a unit test
2. Testing setters and getters
3. Disabled unit tests
4. Commented out unit tests
5. Unit tests that break one per day or week (they erode your confidence and your willingness to write unit tests)
6. Any test that takes more than 10s to execute
7. Unit tests that are longer than 50 lines (incl. all the setup code)

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be yes, writing tests is still writing code and the best way to avoid bugs is to not write the code in the first place.

IMHO, writing good tests is generally harder than writing good code. You can't write a useable test until you understand the problem, both in how it should work and how it can fail. The former is generally much easier to understand than the latter.

Having said all that, you have to start somewhere and sometimes it's easiest to write the simplest tests first, even if then don't really test anything useful.
However, you should winnow those tests out as you work through the TDD process. Work towards having a test set that documents just the external interfaces of an object. This is important, as when you come back to the object for later refactoring, you want a set of tests that defines the responsibilities of the object to the rest of the program, not the responsibilities of the object to itself.

(i.e. you want to test the inputs and outputs of the object as a "black box", not the internal wiring of the object. This allows you as much freedom to change w/o causing damage outside of the object. )